# How can I add a Button() inside of TextEditor() in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I'd like try be able to add buttons inside of TextEditor() or a custom text editor.
Is this possible with SwiftUI?

Comment: What do you mean 'inside', is this a kind of overlay or in ZStack with a different zIndex? Or it's an attachment like UIKit?

Comment: I'm thinking something like this. I'd like the text to be editable by the user. And when they delete, it deletes the button "element"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d97BH.png

Comment: I don't think SwiftUI can support this, you better use textStorage and UITextView from UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by using a ZStack e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Type your text here..."

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .trailing, vertical: .top)) {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .padding()
                .border(Color.gray, width: 1)

            Button(action: {
                // Action for the button
                print("Button was tapped")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding([.top, .trailing], 20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```